# Solutions for uploading a large file to Amazon Web Services from local machine

Tags: file, amazon-web-services, upload

I need to update a large file to Amazon Web Services (5GB) , the trouble is I would be uploading from my home computer that only has a mediocre ADSL connection, and being ADSL upload is so much slower than download

Download:8Mb/s
Upload  :0.4 Mb/s

So it would take a long time, also my internet connection drops out at least once a day so any upload that could not be restarted would be doomed to failure

Any ideas ?

Comment: AWS supports multi-part upload. Check this link https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/11/10/Amazon-S3-Introducing-Multipart-Upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are uploading to Amazon S3 - then you can make us of multi-part upload. You break down the file into smaller part; give a sequence number for each part. You upload them one by one, once it is done you can re-assemble those pieces into a single big file. More info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html)

The other alternative - it is **kind of of overkill** given that the size of the file is 5GB only. There is a service from AWS called as **[Amazon Import Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/)**; where you will put the data to uploaded in AWS in a Storage Drive / Disk and ship it to Amazon and they upload it and return back your disk. **Also another reason not to consider this is that the handling fees for a storage disk is over $80 (varies region to region) so, it is not economical at all.**

Comment: Both good answers, trouble is if I worked it out correctly (the times above are megabits) the quickest I could upload is 28 hours, wish I had access to some fast upload connection.

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you are located. I can suggest you take a holiday trip with your laptop to any destination which has good internet speed; Get connected to a fast internet there upload and enjoy your holiday. Or go meet a old pal who lives in a city and get your upload done at his house. I see this to be cheap and social.